# when plotting a pdf in python for a normal distribution and the standard deviation is 2, will the mean still be zero?

Tags: python, standards, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

So based on my understanding of normal distribution the mean is zero by default when the standard deviation is 1. I was given an assignment to write a python program to generate a PDF of a normally distributed function with the range from 10 to 45 with a standard deviation of 2. Will the mean still be zero? I tried this but my plot doesn't form a bell shape. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
mu=0 # mean
sigma=2
x=np.arange(10,45,0.1)
y=stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, sigma)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

See my plot here: [myplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDB6V.jpg)

Comment: The bell shape forms around the mean value (here: zero) but you are looking at the range 10 to 45 which is a part of the right side of the shape only.

Comment: Okay I get that. I wanted to verify if the mean should still be zero or am I supposed to find the mean for the plot? If so, do i find the mean with np.mean()?

Comment: The location parameter (second in `pdf` call) is `0` which at least in case of normal distribution is equal to mean value.

Comment: Ohkay thanks, I changed the mean to the mean of the 10,45 range. It looks more like a distribution now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here since the range of random variables is between 10 to 45, so the mean will lie in between this range of values, around 27. You need to get the same using the mean function and then use your code as follows:

```
y=stats.norm.pdf(x, x.mean(), sigma )
```

This will give you a normal distribution curve
[image: Code snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(10,45,0.1)
sigma = 2
print('Mean :', round(x.mean(), 2),'SD :', sigma)
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x,x.mean(),sigma), 'r1', lw=2, alpha=0.5, label='norm PDF')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Which prints:

```
Mean : 27.45 SD : 2
```

And shows the shape of the probability density function:

[image]

Comment: Wekcine to StackOverflow. Please provide an explanation for your code so that a new learner can understand your solution.